# Unable to define styles for font

Tags: html, css, fonts, styles

I am experiencing an issue whereby I can't define any font styles on my page. I have tried several different methods and search the net for hours to no avail. Any Help is appreciated. I am trying to change the font in the text box to tahoma and white.

Here is the site for reference: [site](http://www.travismoore.co.uk)

---

```
body 
{
   font-family:Tahoma;
   margin:0;
   padding-top:98px;
   padding-bottom:47px;
   background:#000  url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%;
}

p
{
   font-family: Tahoma; 
   color:#000;
}

.socialimg {margin: 3px 2px 0px 2px}

#header_container {
   background:#000;
   height:65px;
   left:0;
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
   top:0; 
}

#header{
   padding-top:1px;
   line-height:65px;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
}

#menu_container {
   background:url(../images/menu-ss.png) repeat;
   height:42px;
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
   margin-top:65px;
   top:0;
}

#menu{
   line-height:42px;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:555px;
}

#container {
   margin:0 auto;
   overflow:auto;
   width:100%;
}

#content{
   width:400px;
   background:#000;
   margin-top:50px;
   margin-left:5em;
   border-radius:15px;
   -moz-border-radius:15px;
   border:1px solid #292829;
}

#content_box1 {
   width:370px;
   padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#fs_container {
   background:url(../images/fs.png) repeat-x;
   height:8px;
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
   margin-bottom:48px;
}

#fs {
   line-height:8px;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:940px;
   text-align:center;
}

#footer_container {
   background:#000  url(../images/stripe.png) repeat;
   border:1px solid #292829;
   bottom:0;
   height:47px;
   left:0;
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
}

#footer {
   line-height:47px;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:98%;
   text-align:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Travis Moore</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="header_container">
    <div id="header">
        <img alt="Logo" src="images/logo.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="menu_container">
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="main_menu">
           <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MEDIA</a>
              <ul>
              <li><a href="#">PHOTOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">VIDEOS</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li> <a href="#">PROJECTS/EXPERIANCE</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
       <div id="content_box1"><p>testtesttesttesttesttest testtesttesttesttesttest</p></div>
     </div>

</div>

<div id="fs_container">
<div id="fs"></div></div>

<div id="footer_container">
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="socialimg">
       <a href="http://www.twitter.com/travis_moore"><img alt="Twitter" src="images/twitter.png"></a>
         <a href="http://www.youtube.com/travismoore"><img alt="Youtube" src="images/youtube.png"></a>
       <a href="http://www.facebook.com/travismoorebassist"><img alt="Facebook" src="images/facebook.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've visited you're site, the text in the textarea is Tahoma already, its font color is black,

Comment: Use #fff for white instead of #000 in css for p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user2042587's answer is efficient to answer your question but on the other hand if you dont want to use body because it might also affect other pages with body, you could wrap you body with div and give  it a class. Something like this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<body>

//some codes here
//
</body>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper
{
color:#fff;
font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

Full Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y77g/5/)

Answer (score 0):

White color is `#fff`, not `#000`. http://jsfiddle.net/k47Nx/

Next time use JSFiddle instead of posting your source here.

Comment: Sorry have been coidng for a two days solid... making stupid mistakes. Thanks for the help and a will use JSFiddle in the future